# Using Component's member variables in a JS file

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I access a component's variables inside a js file in angular?

example:

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor() {}

}
```

Now how do I access the `title` variable in a file, say `sample.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, misread the question on my mobile on the first go round.

This is a bit more straightforward. I'd definitely be interested to see other ways of going about this if anyone else has any input on the matter.

You'll need to set up your script.ts as an injectable class(or service) for the output from to be rendered in other elements of your application. This service will then either have to be registered as a provider on the app level or on the tree of the child which you pass the resource to.

If you need to have a `script.js`, you'll need to use the service as an intermediary as the service acts as a singleton through which you can provide the resource.

Furthermore, the component which you are passing the resource from will need to be registered as a provider on either the component you are passing to or in the app.modules

```
// my.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    passedVar;
    otherPassedVar;

    constructor(myComponent: MyComponent) {
       // Do something with the variables from my component
       this.passedVar = myComponent.resource;
       this.otherPassedVar = myComponent.getOtherResource();
    }
}

// my.component.ts

// decoration excluded for brevity
export class TestComponent {
    resource = 'some resource this is';

    getResource() {
        return 'this is some other resource';
    }
}

// other.component.ts

@Component({
   selector: '....',
   template: `{{ res1 }} <br> {{ res2 }}`,
   providers: [MyService, MyComponent]
})
export class OtherComponent {
    res1;
    res2;
    constructor(myService: MyService) {
        this.res1 = myService.passedVar;
        this.res2 = myService.otherPassedVar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? I still can't figure how to access it.

Comment: This says how to share data from js to the component, but what I need is the other way around. I can't see how to access the data member of a class, say, AppComponent from the script.js file.